# Refresh CSS styles? (Repaint page)

Tags: javascript, css, cordova

This is one weird issue that I encountered. I've been developing an app with Cordova (Phonegap), and many elements' styles depend on the class I set on `body`. For example,

```
.gray .background{
    background: gray;
}
.gray .title{
    color: white;
}
```

When I do

```
document.body.classList.add("gray");
```

all the styles on the page should change to the "new" style. However, there's one device that I tested on is acting strange. The style did not get updated, however through some logging of the class through JS I know that the class has been added. For some reason the style remains unchanged. This doesn't always happen, sometimes it does, sometimes it behaves correctly.

So, is there a way to manually "trigger" an update to the styles?

Comment: Maybe there are other selectors with the same specificity that are conflicting?

Comment: @Barmar - I don't think so. When I repeat the same action, sometimes it works but sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Does the same happen when you add the class through another method, say, `className += ' gray'`?

Comment: @MrLister - Hm, I never thought that approach. I'll try it later.

Comment: you can rule out the possibility of a specificity issue entirely: if you add `!important` to your rule (before the semicolon) and it still doesn't work as expected, then you know for sure that specificity isn't at fault.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow - I'm sure that specificity isn't the cause since on other devices I tested including on a desktop browser they all worked perfectly fine. Using the method Ali Naci Erdem suggested below I realized that it simply wasn't redrawing after the style got updated.

Comment: glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a pretty solution but on some Android devices I've solved similar problems only by a timeout like;

```
setTimeout(function () {

    document.body.classList.add("gray");
}, 0);
```

The timout of "0" generally works but in some rare cases even later execution is needed.

The above code will wait for all the execution queue to catch up and changes the class. Especially on some low performance devices some changes have not enough time to be rendered while JS is executing (possibly due to a bug in HTML renderer).

But it is also important to keep in mind that your code may have other parts that may result in this behaviour.

Also it is possible to force the browser to redraw using the method explained in [Force Redraw](http://martinwolf.org/2014/06/10/force-repaint-of-an-element-with-javascript/)
If this still does not solve the issue, the redraw itself can be delayed using a SetTimeout.

Comment: This seems to work for now. I'll keep testing a few more times just to make sure.

Comment: Nope, it happened again.

Comment: Hmm... Maybe you can try something like [link](http://martinwolf.org/2014/06/10/force-repaint-of-an-element-with-javascript/) and a combination of both.

Comment: The link you included in your comment actually worked in my case! Thank you so much. (You might want to include that in your answer)

Comment: I've included it for completeness. Thank you!